# Can I use my USB keyboard and mouse on the Ubuntu flagship tablet

Tags: m10

I'm considering to give [the BQ Aquaris M10 Ubuntu Edition](http://www.ubuntu.com/tablet/devices) a trial as my main development machine.

Since I don't need much, just my vim, a browser and a terminal, I think it might be a nice replacement of my laptop. However, I do need a large second screen, which is advertised to work over HDMI, and my mechanical keyboard to work. Which is USB.

Do USB input devises like mice and keyboards work on this devise? Can I plug them in? Or would I need some USB to bluetooth hub to connect one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you will need to buy a micro USB to standard USB hub. I bought this one:
https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B00EUZN6MA/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o02_s00

I use my m10 with a bluetooth keyboard, mouse and speakers (all separateluy connected) and use the USB hub for managing a GPS device. All work together. Just to confirm though that I have also previously tested the tablet with a USB mouse and keyboard via the above device.

I have not tried connecting an external monitor. You will need micro HDMI to standard HDMI converter for this.

Note that is is currently challenging to install dev tools on the device. Read the other questions on here to see if this will be a problem for you.